# How to use a combobox for filtering search in excel data?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code in order to use one of the options in my Combobox to create a filtered search but when I hit the search button I get an error that says that the criteria argument is not defined. I don't know why as I declared my criteria to be the value of my Combobox.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim Frequency As String
Dim wsTL2 As Worksheet
Set wsTL2 = Worksheets("Task List 2")
Frequency = ComboBoxFreq.Value
Dim rngC As Range
Set rngC = wsTL2.Range("C")

wsTL2.ListObjects(rngC).Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria:=Frequency & "*"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?  What value is in `rngC` ?

Answer (score 0):

Few things here, let's start from the top based on below assumptions:

- you want `rngC` to be the whole table, to be filtered by column `C`.
- the table itself is not formatted as a 'table' (as that isn't shown in your screenshot)

The below range set is incorrect

```
Set rngC = wsTL2.Range("C")
```

Assuming you want to select only column `C` it would need to be

```
Set rngC = wsTL2.Range("C:C")
```

You can then set the Autofilter like so, pay particular attention to the `Criteria1` setting, though this would now only filter column `C`

```
rngC.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Daily" 'as an example
```

If you want the whole table to be filtered by column `C` you need to set the correct `Range` object, like so:

```
Set rngC = wsTL2.Range("A1:C100") 'assuming that is the range of the data
```

If your table is indeed a 'table' that would make it a 'ListObject' as per your original code.

if that is the case, you need the name or index of the table (if you have set this through 'Format as Table' function in XL, then the name is likely 'Table1') and then simply set the `rngC` object to the be the range of `Table1` object, like so:

```
Set rngC = wsTL2.ListObjects("Table1").Range
```

and subsequently set the filter as per the above `Autofilter` setting of `rngC` on the assumption you want to filter on column `C`

```
rngC.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Daily" 'as an example
```

So, fundamentally, the `Autofilter` method is -always- applied to a range, it is upto you to ensure you correctly set the relevant range?

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback I ended up setting my range to the correct one as well as adding headers to those columns. When I execute the code however it turns them into those drop down lists but I would like for it to just make the shit show only the dailys for example or only the weekly's and so on.